# matplotlib - Comparing 3 dataframes in bar plot shape

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

There are three dataframes with the same column name but different row counts as below:

```
df1 - 60 rows - column: hour
df2 - 95 rows - column: hour
df3 - 115 rows - column: hour


df1
+-----+------+
|     | hour |
+-----+------+
| 1   | 12   |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 04   |
+-----+------+
| 3   | 15   |
+-----+------+
| ... | ...  |
+-----+------+
| 60  | 18   |
+-----+------+

df2
+-----+------+
|     | hour |
+-----+------+
| 1   | 03   |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 06   |
+-----+------+
| 3   | 12   |
+-----+------+
| ... | ...  |
+-----+------+
| 95  | 14   |
+-----+------+

df3
+-----+------+
|     | hour |
+-----+------+
| 1   | 17   |
+-----+------+
| 2   | 09   |
+-----+------+
| 3   | 10   |
+-----+------+
| ... | ...  |
+-----+------+
| 115 | 20   |
+-----+------+
```

The goal is to show the count of the hours in each dataframe  based on the hour.

```
For example:
df1 has 12 rows (entries) at 4 o'clock. (count of rows in df1 at 4 o'clock)
df2 has 20 rows (entries) at 4 o'clock. (count of rows in df2 at 4 o'clock)
df3 has 8 rows (entries) at 4 o'clock. (count of rows in df3 at 4 o'clock)

These three make 3 bars near each other on 4 (x axis).
```

And the same for other hours on x axis (24 on x axis)

I tried the below codes but faild!

```
pldf = pd.DataFrame(df1, df2, df3,
    index=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
           "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18",
           "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24"]
)
pldf.plot(kind="bar")
```

I would like to have Something like the below photo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the dataframes adding a key to tell where each comes from.
And then use seaborn's [`countplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html).  In the example code below the added key column is called 'origin' and used for the coloring (`hue='origin'`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'hour': np.random.randint(1, 25, 60)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'hour': np.random.randint(1, 25, 95)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'hour': np.random.randint(1, 25, 115)})

pldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], names=['origin']).reset_index(0)

ax = sns.countplot(data=pldf, x='hour', hue='origin')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Perfect! thank you. And also your notes about the other features of the codes are very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot directly with Pandas you can create a DataFrame with the counts of the hours on your DataFrames

```
df1_count = df1['hour'].value_counts().sort_index()
df2_count = df2['hour'].value_counts().sort_index()
df3_count = df3['hour'].value_counts().sort_index()

pldf = pd.concat([df1_count, df2_count, df3_count], 
keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], axis=1)

pldf.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct. But I have to choose the answer which came first. I marked your answer as a useful.Thank you.